# Server is going down frequently (CPU 100% usage & load average over 3.5 mostly)

Tags: linux, nginx, php-fpm, load-average

PHP Application hosted on Nginx server going down frequently.

I checked using htop output and cpu usage is 100% and load average is more the 3.

I tried restarting server and well as restarting PHP -FPM, but after the restart same condition occurs

[image]

What may be the possible issue?

Comment: From your screenshot: `uptime 170 days` so the server seems stable. Add more detailed monitoring and/or check the logs of the services you,re running for insights as to why your server slows down, because it can be as simple as too many visitors and/or too little optimization in either the code or backend database. Your question doesn’t provide enough detail to answer that.

Comment: Please include all relevant details about this system.

Comment: @HBruijn I restarted Server and PHP fpm service and then run HTop but it directly shows 100% CPu usage. all CPu is used by PHP FPM

Comment: Look at your Web logs for php files i think that maxbe a Script or cryptominer goes on?